# JS: sequence of execution of functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, callback

I am a Java developer and beating my head to understand how JS calls function inside a function.

```
function mainFunction() {
     //some HTTP Call. Callback is done through chaining. (Total execution time: 10s) -> (1)

     //let b = some HTTP Call. Callback is assigned to local variable a. (Total execution time: 5s) -> (2)

      //console.log("Hi") -- (3)

     //Setimeout(500, ......); --(4)

     // some very long piece of code - (Execution time: 60s) -- (5)
}
```

In timeline, what will be the order of execution of above code?

Do we have any difference (in wait) in Step 1 and Step 2?

Also do we have any difference if these http callbacks leverage AngularJS $http service?

Comment: Assuming you mean specifically execution of the callbacks for the async ones: `3, 5, 4, 2, 1`

Comment: To include the initial invocations of the async ones, it would be as follows, where `init` is the initial call, and `cb` is the callback: `1init, 2init, 3, 4init, 5, 4cb, 2cb, 1cb`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way JavaScript executes is, synchronous statement gets executed first and the asynchronous functions are placed aside in a queue. And they gets executed in FIFO manner.

### Below is Execution sequence.

Step 1 & 2 have ajax(async) call, so they will get registered but wont get called.

Then step 3 will print `console.log` as its not asynchronous code.

On step 4 it only take a code and place in the async queue by JavaScript Engine.

Then step 5 will gets called.

So till now our asynchronous queue has `Step 1,2 & 4`

After Step 5 execution gets completed, compiler evaluates the `function/code` which have placed in async queue. Step 1, Step 2 & then Step 4, but as per their time evaluation their callback will execute like Step 4(400ms), Step 2 (5s) & then Step 1(10s)

Comment: @squint I updated the answer with their time required for execution.. Thanks for heads up sir. :)

Comment: @RohitManglik no..there is not threading mechanism is used to run the code..it will run the code in manner how it gets placed in async queue.. Step 1 then Step 2 then Step 4.